# MIDI Keyboard recording and editing on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, music, music-production

I used to record some music with my Roland XP-10 keyboard using SONAR 4 under Windows XP, with some VST like The Grand Piano and Korg M1. I have recently switched from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu), and now I'm interested in continue doing my work. My old machine (where I used to have Cakewalk SONAR + some VST) is broken, and that software is very expensive.

What I'm looking for? A software that:

- Let me record my MIDI keyboard.
- Let me edit the recorded MIDI data (such as move some notes and all that stuff).
- Let me use VST software such as Korg M1 and The Grand Piano.
- Works on Ubuntu Linux
- Open source or free.