# MIDI to music sheet converter for Linux

Tags: linux, music, command-line, midi, music-sheet

I am looking for a software that converts MIDI files into music notation.

I want the following features:

1. Should work on Linux
2. Should be able to run in terminal
3. Should be able to save the music sheet in a image format: JPEG or PNG

I have tried using musescore, which is an excellent software, but I can't find any command line (shell) interface.

Comment: Related, but for Windows: [Program to convert a MIDI file into music sheets](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4514/185). As the answer is cross-platform, it would match here as well. Further related (but no answers so far) is [MIDI Keyboard recording and editing on Linux (Ubuntu)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10307/185).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a music notation program called [Lilypond](http://lilypond.org/) which includes a command line interface and a command line [midi2ly](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/usage/invoking-midi2ly) converter that will read in a midi file and output a lilypond file.

- Should work on linux **Yes** and OS/X, Windows
- Should be able to run in terminal **[Yes](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/usage/command_002dline-usage)** or GUI for the main program
- Should be able to save the music sheet in a image format: jpeg or png **Yes** *By default saves as both pdf and poscript format but you can specify `-fpng` for png format or `-dbackend=svg` for svg format*
- Price: **Free** - *Gratis & Open Source GNU GPL*

The output of Lilipond is very high quality and the input files, (output from midi2ly), are text files that can easily be tweaked as needed.

While I haven't tested it you should be able to use:

```
midi2ly somefile.md | lilypond --pdf - -o somefile
```

There are a couple of known shortcomings of midi2ly especially when converting midi files that have been recorded by someone playing on a keyboard.

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the command after the `|` ? I am not getting the desired result.